# VSCode debug: entering multiple command-line arguments on a single line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments, vscode-debugger

I know that I can make VSCode prompt me for command-line arguments when launching a program under the debugger by specifying something like this in launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch MyApp",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "program": "MyApp",
            "args": [ "${input:arg}" ],
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "promptString",
            "id": "arg",
            "description": "Enter argument",
            "default": "something"
        },
    ]
}
```

However, this only allows me to enter a single argument.  To enter multiple, I can have multiple entries in the `args` array, one for each argument.

Unfortunately this does not scale when I want to test different combinations of zero to N command-line arguments, as it will require editing launch.json before every invocation.

Is there a way to have VSCode prompt me for all the command-line arguments on a single line, just as I would type them on a terminal?

Comment: I know it's not what you really want but, in case you don't have support for that in VSCode, you could always make your app receive a single string with all the arguments separated by a escape sequence and parse it. E.g. `arg1\narg2\narg3\n...argn`.

Comment: This thread may be of interest to you. It looks quite recent. And it looks like they are saying that VSCode has no support for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-592600592

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks for the pointer.